# How to go from one page to another in django?

Tags: python, django, url

I am new in python programming and I created a project for learning. I have created three html pages when I click on the other page link it's show error **page not found** because url show previous page link with current page link (I don't know how to explain my problem)

**For Example**

I have two page index, home

if I am on index page(url for index page is **"http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/"**) and want to go to the home page when I click on home page link its show an error because the url for home page is **"http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/home/"** and I want home page url like this **"http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/"**. Same thing happen when I want to go from home page to index page but when I write manually, page open correctly

My code

reference code for index.html and home.html links

```
<a class="collapse-item" href="home">Home Page</a>
<a class="collapse-item" href="index">Index Page</a>
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index_view(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

def home_view(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")
```

app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns= [
    path('index/', views.index_view),
    path('home/', views.home_view),
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("app.urls")),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make changes in 'app/urls.py' and 'href' attributes. In django, every URL should be accessed with name.

[image]

Comment: you are unable to copy/paste the text, but uploading an image is less work than typing: triple backquote Ctrl+V triple backquote

Comment: Sorry i was unable to get your context. Is it not recommended to upload image? I code in "kod.so" then copy the image over here for better visualization.

Comment: how can I search for words in an image, and the image is not stored on an SO site, so it can disappear anytime, now I have to type all text instead of copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

From [django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url), you can use `url` tag of django, for using url tags you have to give name in the `path` function in `urls.py` file.

Try this:

app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns= [
    path('index/', views.index_view,name='index'),
    path('home/', views.home_view,name='home')
]
```

In your `template` file you can use in following way:

```
<a class="collapse-item" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home Page</a>
<a class="collapse-item" href="{% url 'index' %}">Index Page</a>
```

> `Note:` function based views like you have defined `index_view` and `home_view`, doesn't require `view` suffix. Only class based views require `view` suffix. So, it will be better if you use `index` and `home`.